# How can I turn a txt file into a string just using its path?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So I have a program that turns a .txt file into a string to then send it via bluetooth to a printer, the problem is that right now I'm doing it using the file name but I wanted to do it only using the path of the file, this has to do with the fact that I need to search on the folder for any existing txt files and if there are any I need to print the first one and then delete it, so I can't be doing it by using the file's name. This is my code so far:

```
 private fun readFile() String {
    val file = File(storage/emulated/0/IS4-PDF-RDP/00233116695912019091310005913BLUETOOTH.txt)
    var ins InputStream = file.inputStream()
     read contents of IntputStream to String
    var content = ins.readBytes().toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
    return content
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your explanation at all, but https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html

Comment: Hmm basically I want to select a .txt file that is inside of a folder and then turn it into a string the thing is this file won't always have the same name, so I can't use its name like I did on my code there, I need to use its path so instead of doing something like:   
val file = File(storage/emulated/0/IS4-PDF-RDP/00233116695912019091310005913BLUETOOTH.txt)    

I would like to do something more like 

val file = File(storage/emulated/0/IS4-PDF-RDP/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the first file in the folder read it and then delete it as per your requirements

```
File("/storage/emulated/0/IS4-PDF-RDP/").walk().find {
    it.extension == "txt"
}?.apply {
     inputStream().readBytes().toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
     delete()
}
```